# Can unplugged wires electrocute you

Tags: wiring

Can wires such as headphone electrocute . In this specific sitution if headphone wires were twisted or cheek on can they electrocute you. What about unplugged wiredz

Comment: This question needs some serious work to even be legible, let alone acceptable on this site. What does "cheek on" even mean? To give some attempt at an answer: Yes, if the wire is struck by lightning while you're holding it.

Comment: It appears that English is not your first language. Please edit your user profile to make this clear. If you are still in school you should mention that too so we can make allowances.

Comment: `unplugged wires` ... where would the electric current come from? ... can touching your bicycle electrocute you?

Comment: why are you asking? ... did you get zapped?

Comment: Yes, you can be electrocuted (killed) by headphone wires if they contact some source of high voltage such as the mains and there is a path to ground through your body. For example, if a faulty charger is used with an iPod. Or the unplugged wires contact an exposed conductor.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Headphone amplifiers put out about 1 V. This is not enough to feel, never mind cause an electric shock.